# How to update table after immediate insertion in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am inserting into a table with 5 rows and here after inserting every row I have to take the id and need to insert into other table.

```
TABLE NAME: A
TABLE NAME: B
```

In `TABLE A` coloumns are : first `id` will get genarate and this id will be used for some other tables.

```
id id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
```

After some time Table B will get inserted with 5 rows.

**TABLE B:**

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now I have to update table A coloumns with

```
id1 = 1, id2 = 2, id3 = 3, id4 = 4, id5 = 5
```

I am trying with scope identity, it is providing last row id only to me.

Can anybody suggest what would be the approach to achieve this?

```
select top 5 id 
from table B 
order by 1 desc
```

will not work for me.

```
insert into table B values(id1)
insert into table B values(id2)
insert into table B values(id3)
insert into table B values(id4)
insert into table B values(id5)
```

After all these insertions I need to update `Table A`

```
update Table A 
set id1fromA = id1,
    id1fromA = id2,
    id1fromA = id3,
    id1fromA = id4,
    id1fromA = id5
```

Can anybody suggest what would be the approach to achieve this.

Comment: @shanky what was the problem, may i know why it gone for -ve.

Comment: I've formatted your question as best I could, but I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking here. I don't see the actual problem you have

Comment: Buddy I did not downvote. Whenever I do I give reason..... To whoever has downvoted, its always good to leave a comment why you are downvoting this would allow OP to edit his question and make it more clear

Comment: @Tanner: when i am inserting multiple rows at the same time in a table, i have to capture those id's and need to update these values into other table. I can't update these records immediate insertion , because that script will insert 1000000 records into the different tables. Please suggest

Comment: @chaithanyakishore without any clue about how you insert the data is difficult to give you an answer. is there an external program that makes many single insert call? if so, how you understand that the insert is over and you have to gather the ids? is a bulk import task? or a stored procedure that receive a list as input and has to accomplish the task? how you generate the ids? identity, sequence, guid? are they sequential or random? after these many insert how do you identify the relevant ids? is concurrency/multitasking involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @id1 INT ,
    @id2 INT ,
    @id3 INT ,
    @id4 INT ,
    @id5 INT

INSERT  INTO TABLEB
VALUES  ( id1 )
SET @id1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT  INTO TABLEB
VALUES  ( id2 )
SET @id2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT  INTO TABLEB
VALUES  ( id3 )
SET @id3 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT  INTO TABLEB
VALUES  ( id4 )
SET @id4 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT  INTO TABLEB
VALUES  ( id5 )
SET @id5 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


UPDATE  TableA
SET     id1fromA = @id1 ,
        id2fromA = @id2 ,
        id3fromA = @id3 ,
        id4fromA = @id4 ,
        id5fromA = @id5
```